# How ListView can Stop at each element in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

My question is very simple but I did not find a result.

In a ListView.builder (with horizontal scroll) for example if there are 5 elements the user can scroll them all at once. **I would like that the user can scroll only 1 by 1.**

In short I would like the animation of the list **to stop at each element.**

Example of my list :

```
Widget _list()
  {
    return ListView.builder(
        physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        scrollDirection: _horizontalDisplay? Axis.horizontal : Axis.vertical,
        itemCount: data!.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index)
        {
          return widgetToDisplay(index);
        }
    );
  }
```

Comment: That's not the function of ListView.builder.
You can use cards for the same. In listview.builder, you can use cards and that will change after every scroll.

Comment: I think, you need to implement pagination and Animated list together.

Comment: I think you should be looking for the [`PageView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) class

Answer (score 1):

The ListView.builder can't make it, you need to use [carousel_slider package](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider)